# Get vector location list from matrix list via script node in Animation Nodes

Tags: scripting, animation-nodes, vector, matrix

I want to be able to view the coordinates of the locations of the matrices after I have manipulated the matrices with matrix nodes. Would someone be able give me an example script, which I assume would be a loop to show the extracted vector list from matrices in the viewer at the top right as shown in the screen shot I took. The viewer is attached to vects a vector list socket. I have been trying, searching with no success for solution.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually worked out how to make the loop in the script nodeto extract the vectors into a vector list.
[image]

Comment: Is there any reason not to use ``Decompose Matrix`` node?

Comment: I just wanted learn how to program it to learn python.